# How do I center my Navbar?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I looked on here before, but nothing really worked.
I am using Bulma Framework which I believe is relatively unheard of, yet I was hoping you could help me center the brand link on the navbar. This is what I have it at right now:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  color: white;
  height: 9%;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand > .navbar-item,
.navbar .navbar-brand .navbar-link {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Wavehaus';
}
```

I have a link on Codepen so that it can be visualized:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BwrWwg

Note that the font will not show up.

Comment: It was ONE tag, doesn't need a dislike or an edit.

Comment: Also you can use nav-center class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to set the right `display` for the `navbar`. Currently, Bulma makes use of Flex Layout. Now clearing the flex and making it use `block` will make it work:

```css
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand > .navbar-item,
.navbar .navbar-brand .navbar-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: There you go. Accepted

Comment: @AndrewChon There you go... Got some nice points... `:D` Happy Stack Overflowing.

Answer (score 3):

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  color: white;
  height: 9%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its the case (maybe I understood it wrong), but you can add to `navbard-brand` property `margin: auto`

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Bulma` is using flex. You could try adding another `navbar` item after logo if you want to keep the logo

```
< a class="navbar-item center">Table of Content</a>
```

And then you can change the `flex` property of this item (only this item) to

```
.navbar-item.center {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

So that this item occupies the rest of the spaces. Seems working for me.